# My localhost Apache2 PHP UTC has a minute delay

Tags: php, apache, timezone, utc

I am trying to set the timezone for my Apache PHP server to get the UTC, and it tells everything is ok, but the datetime I get when retrieving dates is wrong.

I have set in the php.ini the date.timezone like this:

```
date.timezone=UTC
```

The info shown realated to date:

```
phpinfo();
```

[image]

But the real UTC datetime is 1 minutes ahead, so for example if i run

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

I get 2020-05-06 23:59:11 and real UTC is 2020-05-07 00:00:11

I need this to be precise because of Google 2FA Authenticator, to match the codes.

Any suggestion will be well received!
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most computer clocks are not perfect at keeping time and will naturally drift one way or the other over time. This is why we have [NTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) to synchronize our clocks with special clocks that *are* accurate, and [NTPd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ntpd) to *keep* our local clocks in sync.

How to synchronize your system clock is highly dependent on your OS, with several different flavors of NTPd. If you have further questions about how to specifically configure NTP/NTPd for your OS they would be best asked on https://superuser.com/.